# How to detect if code runs in browser in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, strict-mode

I'm rewriting ES5 JavaScript code into TypeScript and have code like this:

```js
var is_browser = (function() {
    try {
        return this === window;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
})();
```

First thing is that I've got an error from TS that `this` is implicit of type any. But I don't think it matters much because the code will not work since TypeScript is using `"use strict"` for every file, so `this` will be `undefined`.

So what is the proper way to test if JavaScript code runs in the browser?

Comment: can't you write this part in javascript, and just add file declaration in typescript ?

Comment: or you can use `globalThis.window === globalThis`

Comment: The existence of the variable `window` itself indicates that you are in a browser. What that code is doing is exactly this, it's dereferencing `window` and if it throws, then the variable doesn't exist and you're not in a browser

Comment: you could also check if window is not undefined: `typeof window !== 'undefined'`

Comment: @CristianTraìna sure but what about jsDOM I want to detect the browser, not the window object.

Comment: @MauricioRobayo This will break in multiple ways example in jsDOM in Node that also has a window object.

Comment: @AhmedLazhar I think that this is the right way. Thanks. You can add an answer with this solution.

Comment: @jcubic Thanks but I think MauricioRobayo solution should be accepted since it works with all browsers, `globalThis` don't work on old browsers check this link: https://caniuse.com/?search=globalThis

Comment: Which features of the browser do you intend to use? Simply checking for `window` doesn't guarantee that the other features that you want are there. (e.g. [Deno](https://deno.land/) has `globalThis.window`, but it's not a browser). You should feature-detect each API that you intend to use.

Comment: @AhmedLazhar I specifically written a proper way, typeof is not a proper way, which may break in jsDOM. That's why I've written a hack with `this` I want bulletproof code, not something that can break anytime. I'm working on a JavaScript library that can be used in different places.

Answer (score 3):

This solution should always work however the global context is polluted

```
var is_browser = Object.getPrototypeOf(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(globalThis)
) !== Object.prototype
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for so that it works in NodeJs even when someone manually defines `window` globally

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the browser window should not be undefined:

```js
var is_browser = typeof window !== 'undefined';

console.log(is_browser)
```

Comment: This will break `var windows = 10;` Also it will break when testing in jest framework that use jsDOM.

Comment: fair point @jcubic, thanks for the feedback. Although your question was titled "How to **detect if code runs in browser** in TypeScript?" And you explicitly asked "what is the proper way to test if JavaScript code runs **in the browser**?". You never mentioned Jest or jsDOM. Granted, window could be defined by someone else, same as globalThis.

Comment: window can always be defined to point to globalThis

Comment: Sure but this is not the answer I've expected that you can learn in 1 month of learning JavaScript. I wanted something that will work everywhere. Maybe I should write that in the question. But it's kind of silly to add please no answer with `typeof window`. Maybe I should from now on writing a list of answers that I don't want to see.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes is hard to do the simple thing. https://youtu.be/AkYDsiRVqno?t=1037